# Using arcs to represent the vision of characters in my game, having trouble wrapping arc around walls

Tags: java, graphics, 2d

Right now, my game simply draws the vision cone of characters through walls. I want the arc to be interrupted when it reaches a wall, but continue in points where it does not reach a wall.

Here is a quick [example](http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=20777) of what I want to happen.

I am fairly new to programming, I have been programming for about 6 months, but I am very competent in math so please be simple in programming terminology, thank you.

Here is my [GitHub](https://www.github.com/woohoojin/touch) if you want a better feel for my game.

Comment: Please don't put long Google redirect URLs in your question, but rather use the URL you are redirected to.

Comment: sorry, I'm in school right now, and the actual URL is blocked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out how far your character can see in any given direction by casting a ray from the character in that direction and stopping when it hits an obstacle. The details of how to do that for your particular case are going to vary based on how objects are represented in your game.

In the article you link to, it looks like walls are made from lines. If that's the case in your game, you could find the intersection of a ray and each line segment of a wall. If they intersect, then the point at which they intersect is the farthest you can see in that direction.

If, instead, you represent objects as sprites at a given location, you could start by casting the ray and seeing if it intersects the bounding box of a sprite. (The bounding box is just a rectangle around the sprite that completely contains it, as tightly as possible.) Once you know your ray intersects the bounding box, you can look more closely at that object to see if the [ray actually hits the sprite](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ray+sprite+intersection).